# Drawing a circle with radius = 40 miles around Bunnell, Florida

Tags: geography

The following works:

```
p1=GeoPosition[Bunnel(city)];
With[{r=40mi},
 GeoGraphics[{Red,  GeoCircle[p1, r], Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[p1]},
   GeoScaleBar -> Placed["Miles", {Right,  Center}],
   Frame->True,
   PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Bunnell,  Florida"], 16, Bold, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]],
   ImageSize -> 700]
```

The following (on the other hand) doesn't work:

```
p1=GeoPosition[Bunnel(city)];
With[{r=40mi},
 GeoGraphics[{Red,  GeoCircle[p1, r], Blue,  PointSize[Large], Point[p1]},
   GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{0, 40}mi, {Right,  Center}],
   Frame->True, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Bunnell, Florida"], 16, Bold, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]],
   ImageSize -> 700]
```

GeoScaleBar seems to have a "bug"; it allows "km" (kilometers) but, not "mi" (miles).  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

It actually seems to work fine. You may have been tripped up by the use of `Quantity` and units, which may be a tad less than intuitive sometimes:

```
p1 = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Bunnell", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}]];
With[{r = Quantity[40, "Kilometers"]},
 GeoGraphics[
  {Red, GeoCircle[p1, r], Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[p1]},
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[Quantity[{0, 40}, "Kilometers"], p1],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["Bunnell, Florida"], 16, Bold, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]],
  ImageSize -> 700
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that I changed the positioning of the `GeoScaleBar`; since it accepts a position specified by `GeoPosition`, I used `p1` to position the start of the scale bar exactly at the same position as the reported coordinates of the city.

Comment: Thank you for your help; I tested the above code with Miles and it works!